# Can one replace keywords in functions by a dict or sth?

Tags: python, function, keyword

I have a function with plenty of predefined parameters (test.addstrategy within the function runstrat).

I would like to change the keywords **selcperc**=p1, **mperiod**=int(p2) to **rperiod** and **zperiod**. These are also parameters in the St function.

Is that possible by forinstance a dict like the globalparams dict?

```
globalparams = dict(fromdate=datetime.datetime(2005, 11, 3),
                    todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 18),
                    strategy="St",                                  
                    
                    #Heatmap section
                    heatmap=True,  
                    heatmapparams= {'selcperc': "p1"},
                    heatmapparams2= {'mperiod': "int(p2)",
                                    'printlog': "False"},
                    )

if globalparams["heatmap"]:
    results_list = []
    for i in np.arange(0.02, 0.12, 0.02):
        for j in np.arange(60, 250, 10):
            PnL = runstrat(p1=i, p2=j)
            results_list.append([i, j, i, PnL])
    my_heatmap1(results_list)
    return

def runstrat(p1, p2):
    test= bt.Cerebro()
    test.addstrategy(eval(globalparams["strategy"], selcperc=p1, mperiod=int(p2),printlog=False)

    for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(globalparams["path"], '*')):
        df = pd.read_csv(fname, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
        if len(df)>200:
            test.adddata(bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df,name=os.path.basename(fname).replace(".csv", ""),fromdate=fromdate, todate=todate, plot=False))        

    test.run(maxcpus=0)
    return test.broker.getvalue()

                     
def my_heatmap1(data):
    data = np.array(data)
    xs = np.unique(data[:, 1].astype(int))
    ys = np.unique(data[:, 0].astype(float))
    vals = data[:, 3].reshape(len(ys), len(xs))
    min_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(vals, axis=None), vals.shape)
    max_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(vals, axis=None), vals.shape)

    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'chartreuse', 'limegreen'])
    ax = sns.heatmap(vals, xticklabels=xs, yticklabels=ys, cmap='viridis', annot=True, fmt='.2f')

    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(min_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(max_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))
    print(data)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

St is another very lengthy class.

Edit:

I did now a poor workaround by incl. all parameters i potentially want to change. in the global params I set up a dictionary that contains all cases, which will replace the arguments with the relevant case...

Answer (score 0):

The keywords are defined by the function being called, there's no way the caller can change them.

Comment: Actually the keywords are merely parameters stored in a dicts in the function. Hence, if the keywords change the parameters that are already set by default in the function will take their place.